# Saving User Defined Class in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, class, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have class in matlab using classdef as,

```
classdef scores
    %   SCORES Summary of this class goes here
    %   Class for stroring the individual scores array of each of the
    %   comparison of the models and the test files including the number of
    %   coefficients used and number of gaussian 

    properties
        detailed_scores;
        no_of_gauss=0;
    end

    methods
    end
end
```

Created objects and saved into an array as;

```
for i=1:99
    score = scores;
    score.detailed_scores = somescore(:,9);
    score.no_of_gauss = i;
    array = [array score];
end
```

Now, I would want to save it into a matfile as;

```
save('somematfile.mat','array');
```

Is it possible to load this `array` later on to retrieve the data back ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `load somematfile` would just do that.

```
load somemathfile
for k = 1:length(array)
  obj = array(k);
  obj.detailed_scores
end
```

However, you have to be careful if you change the class definition, especially if you remove/rename or add new properties to the class. In that case you may need to implement [saveobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/saveobj.html) and [loadobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/loadobj.html) methods.